# How to Override SaveChanges Using Model First in EF5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mvvm

How can I override the SaveChanges() method in EF5 WITHOUT using a code-first approach?  Some of my tables use a char(32) PK (basically, a stripped down GUID) that must be stuffed prior to save.  Same with the audit trail.  Every search I have tried always assumes that a code-first approach and NOT model-first.

Answer (score 1):

The generated context class is partial. Just add another code file where you extend the class and override `SaveChanges` there.